# If a Death's Head of Bhaal takes damage while it's asleep, can it use its Unstoppable reaction to reduce that damage to 0?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, reactions, unconscious, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus

This came up in a recent session. The [Death's Head of Bhaal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/deaths-head-of-bhaal) (BG:DiA, p. 233) has a reaction called Unstoppable that allows it to reduce the damage from an attack to 0 (3 times per day).

If a Death's Head of Bhaal is asleep (either from a *Sleep* spell or just normally asleep), can they use that reaction to reduce the damage to 0?

Taking damage would ostensibly wake the character up. Also, a creature normally can't take reactions while asleep. As such, I'm not entirely sure whether this reaction could be used to reduce the damage to 0 in this scenario.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Because it threw me for a moment, I feel like it should be pointed out that the "Death's Head of Bhaal" are living humanoid assassins, and seem completely unrelated to the undead "Death's Head" monsters that are flying decapitated heads (and should thus be immune to being put to sleep).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Under the *sleep* spell, it cannot be used.

*Sleep* the spell imposes the unconscious condition:

> - An unconscious creature is incapacitated, can't move or speak, and is unaware of its surroundings.

The incapacitated condition states:

> An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

Since *Unstoppable* requires use of your reaction, it is unavailable while asleep via the *sleep* spell, as you are asleep at the time the reaction trigger occurs.

#### Regular sleep is under-defined unless you use *Xanathar's Guide*.

The [rules for sleeping given in the *Player's Handbook*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Resting) do not tell us that regular sleeping imposes any conditions, so it will be up to the DM to decide if sleeping imposes any condition which restricts use of your reaction. However, if you are using *Xanathar's Guide*, which is optional (ask your DM), we have more clearly defined rules:

> Just as in the real world, D&D characters spend many hours sleeping, most often as part of a long rest. Most monsters also need to sleep. While a creature sleeps, it is subjected to the unconscious condition. Here are a few rules that expand on that basic fact.

If using this rule, Death's Head of Bhaal cannot use its reaction while sleeping (see first section), even conventional sleep not imposed by a spell.

---

In a past revision of this answer, I presented a possible argument for ruling contrary to the previous sections. It was pointed out by user [Blckknght](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/14661/blckknght) in a comment that in the argument, I misapplied one of the rules. If this interests you, check the revision history.

Comment: The first two of my edits were stylistic and I can understand why you would roll them back.  The third is [grammatical](https://www.englishgrammar.org/even-even-if-even-though-and-even-as/), though: "even conventional sleep not imposed by a spell" needs _something_ to connect it to sleeping - a conjunction, preposition, or both.  I believe you are insisting on an incorrect use.

Comment: @Kirt My construction is grammatically correct.

Comment: I think @Kirt is right that the grammar doesn't quite match between "sleeping" and "sleep".  Shouldn't the "even" clause work if it was the only thing "while" was applied to, instead of "sleeping"?  It's not something I trip over while reading, though, so leaving it might be best.  (And maybe that means I'm wrong that there's a problem at all.)  "Even **in** conventional sleep" could work, with the "in" avoiding drawing more attention to itself or to the grammar than most other things I could think of.